# Helper method generates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

My problem is about rails helpers generating wrong links for my user model User

```
<%= link_to "delete", user_registration_path(user), :method => :delete, :confirm => "You sure?" %>
```

Generates the following url:
whatever.com/users.1

My routes.rb:

```
put "rooms/:id/close" => "rooms#close", :as => "close_room"

devise_for :users, path_names: {sign_in: "login", sign_out: "logout"},
controllers: {omniauth_callbacks: "omniauth_callbacks"}
get "home/index"

resource :user do
  # Route GET /user/tandem
  get 'tandem', :on => :collection
  get 'practice', :on => :collection

end

root :to => 'home#index'

resources :rooms
match '/party/:id', :to => "rooms#party", :as => :party, :via => :get
match '/users/find', :to => "users#find", :as => :find_users, :via => :get
# Sample resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
match '/users/edit/:id', :to => "users#edit", :as => :edit_user, :via => :get
resources :users, only: [:index ,:show, :edit, :update]
```

I'm using ruby '1.9.3', 'rails', '3.2.13', devise (2.2.4). It also happens with the edit action.
Edit: My routes file is

```
 close_room PUT      /rooms/:id/close(.:format) rooms#close

 new_user_session GET      /users/login(.:format)                 devise/sessions#new
 user_session POST     /users/login(.:format)                 devise/sessions#create
 destroy_user_session DELETE   /users/logout(.:format)
 devise/sessions#destroy
 user_omniauth_authorize GET|POST /users/auth/:provider(.:format)
 omniauth_callbacks#passthru {:provider=>/facebook/}
 user_omniauth_callback GET|POST /users/auth/:action/callback(.:format) omniauth_callbacks#(?-mix:facebook)
 user_password POST     /users/password(.:format)              devise/passwords#create
 new_user_password GET      /users/password/new(.:format)          devise/passwords#new
 edit_user_password GET      /users/password/edit(.:format)         devise/passwords#edit
                     PUT      /users/password(.:format)                   devise/passwords#update
 cancel_user_registration GET      /users/cancel(.:format)                devise/registrations#cancel
 user_registration POST     /users(.:format)                       devise/registrations#create
 new_user_registration GET      /users/sign_up(.:format)               devise/registrations#new
edit_user_registration GET      /users/edit(.:format)                  devise/registrations#edit
                     PUT      /users(.:format)                       devise/registrations#update
                     DELETE   /users(.:format)                       devise/registrations#destroy
          home_index GET      /home/index(.:format)                  home#index
         tandem_user GET      /user/tandem(.:format)                 users#tandem
       practice_user GET      /user/practice(.:format)               users#practice
                user POST     /user(.:format)                        users#create
            new_user GET      /user/new(.:format)                    users#new
           edit_user GET      /user/edit(.:format)                   users#edit
                     GET      /user(.:format)                        users#show
                     PUT      /user(.:format)                        users#update
                     DELETE   /user(.:format)                        users#destroy
                root          /                                      home#index
               rooms GET      /rooms(.:format)                       rooms#index
                     POST     /rooms(.:format)                       rooms#create
            new_room GET      /rooms/new(.:format)                   rooms#new
           edit_room GET      /rooms/:id/edit(.:format)              rooms#edit
                room GET      /rooms/:id(.:format)                   rooms#show
                     PUT      /rooms/:id(.:format)                   rooms#update
                     DELETE   /rooms/:id(.:format)                   rooms#destroy
               party GET      /party/:id(.:format)                   rooms#party
          find_users GET      /users/find(.:format)                  users#find
               users GET      /users(.:format)                       users#index
                     POST     /users(.:format)                       users#create
                     GET      /users/new(.:format)                   users#new
                     GET      /users/:id/edit(.:format)              users#edit
                     GET      /users/:id(.:format)                   users#show
                     PUT      /users/:id(.:format)                   users#update
                     DELETE   /users/:id(.:format)                   users#destroy
```

Comment: try sign_out_path(user) is that u want

Comment: What action are you trying to accomplish with that link?

Comment: I tryed and it tells me  undefined method `sign_out_path'

Comment: can you add the output of `rake routes`?

Comment: Im trying to accomplish to delete User record

Comment: You are missing :delete in users resource route declaration i guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should change

```
<%= link_to "delete", user_registration_path(user), :method => :delete, :confirm => "You sure?" %>
```

to

```
<%= link_to "delete", user_path(user), :method => :delete, :confirm => "You sure?" %>
```

`user_registration_path` has nothing to do with removing a user - in fact quite the opposite.

**edit**

after seeing your `rake routes` output, it seems there are some other problems - there are multiple paths to destroy users - you should work on correcting that, but the following will definitely work:

```
<%= link_to "delete", {controller: 'users', action: 'destroy', id: @user.id },
                      {method: :delete} %>
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove `resource :user` and move the `tandem` and `practice` routes to `resources :users`

If you wanna retain `/user/tandem` kind of route use like this,

```
resource :user, only => [] do
  #tandem and practice routes as existing
end`
```

And you should add :delete to user resource route declaration.

```
resources :users, only: [:index ,:show, :edit, :update, :delete]
```

and change the `link_to` to `users_path` like

`link_to 'Destroy', users_path(user), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }`

Comment: why're u using `user_registration path` in `link_to`. Can u use `user_path` instread?( `link_to 'Destroy', user_path(user), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }`)

Comment: From the `rake routes` output, I see we should use `users_path(user)` instead of `user_path(user)`. Tried this?

Comment: I tried both of them. It should be something related with the generation of the URL of the helper method. With edit also happens. Instead of generating /users/edit/1, it generates /users/edit.1

Comment: Remove `resource :user` and move the `tandem` and `practice` routes to `resources :users`.